# Wrap several C-Sources (.c files) to use their functions in Python using SWIG

Tags: python, c, interface, wrapper, swig

There are a lot of Tutorials about how to wrap single functions of one .c file. But I want to wrap all functions of several .c files. This is why I included them all in the interface file (interface.i)

```
/*interface.i*/
%module interface
%include source1.c
%include source2.c
%include source3.c
```

I am now wondering if I have to include all header files which appear in the .c files. And also if I have to consider the header files which are addressed in the header files.

Comment: Could you elaborate your intent? Do you want to include the sources in your module? Do you have built a library from the sources?

Comment: I have a library and a bunch of .c files. When I use the library in C I only include the header file and link my code with the dynamic library. But I want to use the functions of this library in Python. Because I can't just link the dynamic library I try to wrap the .c files together to get the same result as with using the dynamic C-library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your C program should have an interface it exposes. For example the source1/2/3.c together with their internal headers source1/2/3.h compile to a foo.dll. Then the interface foo_function.h exposes functions that can be called from outside.

To wrap the external functions you need only the foo_functions.h in your interface.i. You don't need the source1/2/3.h.
The C code may have another foo_constants.h or so, belonging to the interface, with the structs you need and constant definitions that are quite handy. You should add that too.

Additionally you may need some includes from SWIG itself. To generate for example pointer and array handling. Something like:
%include cpointer.i
%pointer_functions(int, intp)
%include carrays.i
%array_functions(unsigned int, uintarray)

Good luck!

Comment: The additional includes are only necessary if I want to manipulate pointer/array, right? Or is it even for internal data handling necessary?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Only if you need it in your Python code.Typically this is needed to prepare data handed over to the C functions as parameters, or to evaluate data got from them as return value.